# AWS - Isolating subnets within a VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Say I have a vpc with network 10.130.0.0/16.

Is there anyway to isolate subnets within this /16 so that they cannot be routed between one another?

say I have 10.130.1.0/24 and 10.130.2.0/24 and I don't want them to talk to each other- is this possible?

I see the entire network as "local" when creating these subnets - would I need to move them out of the vpc to have isolation?

Comment: The answer you accepted is not network isolation, it's network firewalling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do **not** need to move them out of the VPC for isolation. Instead, you can achieve this isolation using the VPC's built-in security features like NACLs and Security Groups.

In AWS, subnets within the same VPC can communicate with each other by default. This is because the main route table of a VPC typically has an entry that allows all subnets in the VPC to communicate with each other. Specifically, you might see a route with a destination of `10.130.0.0/16` (your VPC's CIDR block) and a target of "local", which means all traffic within the VPC is locally routable.

However, if you want to prevent two subnets from communicating with each other, you can do so using Network Access Control Lists (NACLs) or Security Groups (SGs). Here's how you can do it:

1. **Using NACLs**:

   - Network ACLs are stateless, meaning you need to define rules for both inbound and outbound traffic.
   - Create a NACL for each subnet.
   - For subnet `10.130.1.0/24`:

     1. Allow all inbound and outbound traffic.
     2. Add a rule to deny all outbound traffic to `10.130.2.0/24`.
     3. Similarly, add a rule to deny all inbound traffic from `10.130.2.0/24`.
   - For subnet `10.130.2.0/24`, do the opposite:

     1. Allow all inbound and outbound traffic.
     2. Add a rule to deny all outbound traffic to `10.130.1.0/24`.
     3. Add a rule to deny all inbound traffic from `10.130.1.0/24`.
   - Associate each NACL with its respective subnet.
2. **Using Security Groups**:

   - Security Groups are stateful, so if you deny outbound traffic, the corresponding inbound response is automatically denied (and vice-versa).
   - For instances in subnet `10.130.1.0/24`:

     1. Create a security group (let's call it SG1) and assign it to them.
     2. Ensure there is no rule allowing traffic to or from the CIDR `10.130.2.0/24`.
   - For instances in subnet `10.130.2.0/24`:

     1. Create another security group (SG2) and assign it to them.
     2. Ensure there is no rule allowing traffic to or from the CIDR `10.130.1.0/24`.

If both methods are used together, remember that NACLs are applied first, and then Security Groups. So, traffic would have to pass both to be allowed.

Comment: Thank you sir- this is what I ended up going with. I appreciate it

Comment: You can't use security groups for subnets...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [Network ACLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html) to block traffic between subnets.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can isolate subnets by preventing them to be routable to each other.

All subnets created within the VPC are by default associated with the default main route table. You can, however, create custom route tables and you can associate them to the subnets as required.

From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Route_Tables.html):

> Your VPC has an implicit router, and you use route tables to control where network traffic is directed. Each subnet in your VPC must be associated with a route table, which controls the routing for the subnet (subnet route table). You can explicitly associate a subnet with a particular route table. Otherwise, the subnet is implicitly associated with the main route table. A subnet can only be associated with one route table at a time, but you can associate multiple subnets with the same subnet route table.

Comment: would you prefer this method over acl?

Comment: @boog yes. ACL isn't really network isolation, it's essentially firewalling

Comment: I am not sure this works. When you create a new route table, it always creates one or more routes for your VPC CIDR ranges to local. And I don't think you can edit these ranges in the route table. You could change the target to something that would then block the traffic, but that's a hack.

Comment: @mimo yes the target can be changed. it's not a hack, it's known as a black hole and it's a fairly common pattern